# Equality of traces of two matrices

Tags: matrices, trace-map

I was going through Boyd's EE363 HW 4 . In page 11,I found this [image]

I dont understand why the 2 expressions involving trace (in the MSE equation ) are equal to each other .

$\Sigma_{x}$ is postive semidefinite and and $\Sigma_{v}$ is positive definite covariance matrices  is only information used .

Comment: maybe they are positive definite, since you are inverting one of them

Comment: However, you definitively need more informations of the matrices, otherwise it is wrong. Take $A=I$, $\Sigma_x=bI$ and $\Sigma_v = aI$. You have that the first expression is $nab(a+b)^{-1}$ and the second is $na(ab + 1)^{-1}$

Comment: They are probably two equivalent expressions for the same sub-block of a block matrix inverse. See [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) on Wikipedia.